# PHP: 10 minutes left to the DateTime?

Tags: php, datetime

I'm trying to find a way to do something if 10 minutes is left to the end date of a DateTime in PHP.

However, so far i have no luck and I think my logic is wrong. so I need some help/advise.

my current code is this:

```
$end_date= '2015-01-22 20:24:41';

$datetime1 = new DateTime();

$datetime2 = new DateTime($end_date);
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
$finalDate = $interval->format('%d day %h hours %i minutes %s seconds');


$minutes_to_add = 10;

$time = new DateTime($end_date);
$time->add(new DateInterval('PT' . $minutes_to_add . 'M'));


echo  $time->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
echo '<br/>';
echo  $end_date;
echo '<br/>';
if($finalDate > $time){
    echo("result_messageTi=times up");
}else{
    echo("result_messageTi=$finalDate");    
}
```

in the code above, I thought I need to add 10 minutes to the $end_date and then when the `$finalDate` reaches the `$end_date + 10 minutes`, it would execute my (other stuff)... otherwise it would run as usual.. (*please take a note of if/else statements*).

however, I know my login is way off and I cannot figure out how to solve this problem.

so basically, what i need to do is to run the code as normal until there is 10 minutes left to the date and when there is 10 minutes or less is left to the `$finalDate`, I need to `echo("result_messageTi=times up");`

sorry about the long winded question.

any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: a) You're comparing the wrong variables (double check what `$finalDate` actually is!), b) you're adding 10 minutes in the wrong direction (you want 10 minutes **before** your time, not after).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) is a good choice for this sort of thing. It turns your date in to a value in seconds. So 10 minutes is 600 seconds which allows a straighforward comparison. [time()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) gives you the current time in the same form.

So you could try:

```
$end_date= '2015-01-22 20:24:41';
$datetime1 = time();
$datetime2 = strtotime($end_date);
$minutes_to_add = 10;
if( ($datetime2 - $datetime1) < ($minutes_to_add*60) ) {
  echo("result_messageTi=times up");
} else {
// Time is not up
}
```

Comment: appreciate it bud... this did it nicely. I'm sure the other answer would work as well but I've selected yours because I understand it better even though the other answer has less code! lol.. shows how messed up my head is... :D

Answer (score 1):

Unless i misunderstood, you don't need all that code. You can simply do

```
$endTS=strtotime('2015-01-22 09:40:41');
if(time()>$endTS-600)               // 600 = 10m * 60s
  echo("result_messageTi=times up");
```

**[Fiddle](https://eval.in/247545)**